# How to make Nginx rewrite internationalized domains in Unicode instead of ASCII?

Tags: nginx, unicode, idn

I am using a rewrite rule that includes the domain name in the path:

```
rewrite ^/?$ http://example.com/landingpage/$http_host break;
```

This works fine, except for Internationalized domain names in Unicode,

because nginx includes `$http_host` as ASCII characters.

For example, when the requested url is [http://música.com](http://m%C3%BAsica.com)
then the rewrite rule makes it:

```
http://example.com/landingpage/xn--msica-7ua.com
```

while I need the result to be:

```
http://example.com/landingpage/música.com
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935286/apache-cyrillic-wildcards-in-virtualhost-config